# AWS s3 PutObject works from CLI but not Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been give access to a client's AWS S3 bucket using a cross account role. I have set up 2 profiles in my credentials file. One being our IAM account and the other having the cross account role and a reference to our account. Using the CLI I can copy files no problem. Now I try and do this using Python and Boto3. I can assume the role but then I can't copy the file, I get "Access Denied".

```
[client]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[client-car]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/MyCo-CrossAccountAccess-CrossAccountRole-XXXXXXXXXX
source_profile = client
external_id = 0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x
```

If I use this in the CLI the copy works:

```
aws s3 cp my-local-file s3://mybucket/bucket-file --profile client-car
```

This is the Python code:

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts',OUR-ACCOUNT-ACCESSKEY,OUR-SECRET)
account_id = sts_client.get_caller_identity()["Arn"]

assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/MyCo-CrossAccountAccess-CrossAccountRole-XXXXXXXXXX',RoleSessionName='AssumeRoleSession1',ExternalId='0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x')
credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

# No problem until here

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'])    

filename = 'local file to copy'
objectname = 'testing6/testfile66'
bucketname = "the-clients-bucket"
response = s3_client.upload_file(filename,bucketname,objectname) # <- FAILS HERE AccessDenied
```

Comment: `mybucket` and `the-clients-bucket` are supposed to be the same thing, or different? Your question is quite confusing of what are you doing.

Comment: Sorry, it's all going to the client's bucket. I should have made that a bit clearer.

Comment: I have found that it works when I use client.put_object but not client.upload_file. What additional privileges does upload_file require?

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: It might require `UploadPart`.

Comment: Please add the error to the question.

Comment: Many files ranging from a few k to many gb. (Current test file is a few kb)

Error:
boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload C:\Work\testing\testdata0\T00629\00142536\00402639 to bucket-name/testing6/testfile66: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Comment: How big is the file that causes it to fail? Does it fail with the first file, or after several files? Are they all being uploaded to the same name (`testing6/testfile66`) as shown in your code?